# Reject ASP.NET MVC 5 Login POST Http request with 401.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using the vanilla Identity 2.x for authentication in my MVC website. The client side, angularjs is sending a post request to Account controller's Login method.

Now the use case is to reject the http post request with a Http Status Code 401.1 when the User is disabled.

Vanilla Login method returns a bool value based on login success or failure.

I tried sending a Http response with StatusCode set as 401 but the browser receives a 200 OK with the 401 in a header variable.

How do I send a response with 401 and not get it hijacked by the 200 code.

If I use HttpUnauthorized, the browser receives a 500 internal server along with the entire aspx page contents.

I'm using MVC 5.2, C# 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You should throw proper exception - HttpResponseException. Try do it like that:

```
var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "ohhh no!" };    
throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

Comment: The browser receives a 500 StatusCode

Comment: It should redirect the user if the HttpResponse.StatusCode is set to 401, but only if the <authentication /> section of the Web.config is found